# Is it possible to accept user input as part of a remote git post-receive hook?

Tags: git, bash, ssh, hook, tty

I've got a post-receive hook that deploys our master branch whenever we push master.

I'd like to make the deployment optional; the hook asks for simple Y/N response to achieve this; bash pseudo code below:

```
echo "Should I deploy this code now? Enter Y/N"
read deploy_code

case ${deploy_code} in
  "Y") do_a_deploy ;;
  "N") exit ;;
    *) # ask the question again if not Y or N ;;
esac
```

Because of the way the post-receive hook gets its arguments on stdin the  `read`  line doesn't pause for input from the user, and the script loops round and round trying to get a Y/N answer.

I thought that specifically requesting from `/dev/tty` would fix this;

```
read deploy_code < /dev/tty
```

but that still causes the script to loop endlessly, as the input isn't coming from the keyboard.

Is it actually possible to get keyboard input in this circumstance?

**Edit:**
Ah. It looks like it's actually ssh to blame. Looking at the output now I've added the  `< /dev/tty`  I'm seeing */dev/tty: No such device or address*

And I can mimic this if I run the script locally, but over ssh:

```
ssh 127.0.0.1 "echo 40913e300c8bf4ed7ea91b5ef61a522f3be2c05f e2aabfc865547d8b494b76c96947bab0c62acfec refs/heads/master | /path/to/post-receive"
```

**Edit 2:**

So I can either set the -t option to ssh to request a tty as per [enabling tty in a ssh session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372268/enabling-tty-in-a-ssh-session/3372289#3372289) or I could enable it in the authorised_keys file on the server on a per-key basis

**Edit 3:**

After creating ~/bin/ssh-t

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh -tt "$@"
```

(the double -t option forces a tty) and setting GIT_SSH to point to it, I'm now getting the dreaded **fatal: protocol error: bad line length character:** followed by 005 which I guess is something in .bash_profile or similar echoing before git has a chance to run

Answer (score 2):

You could parse the commit comment as well. Git allows empty commits. Just another option.

Comment: It's an interesting option, that I hadn't considered :)