# How can I open a TTY for interaction with git-push hooks?

Tags: ssh, githooks, git-push, post-commit

I am using the git-deploy Ruby gem to deliver an application to the staging server. The deployment is performed with SSH keys.

In my `after_push` script I want to run a command with `sudo`, which subsequently asks for my password, since sudo rights are limited (can't run sudo without password).

Effectively my sudo command fails with:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I've tried adding an askpass program and specifying it according to the git manual.

How can I open a TTY in the `git-push` process for interactive commands in my `after_push` script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far it seems what I am seeking is not possible. There is no tty available, is what I gather from reading [Query on setting up a pre-receive hook in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385089/query-on-setting-up-a-pre-receive-hook-in-git) and [Is it possible to accept user input as part of a remote git post-receive hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809547/is-it-possible-to-accept-user-input-as-part-of-a-remote-git-post-receive-hook)

Any better suggestions for how to perform password protected sudo operations in post-receive?

**UPDATE**: The answer was found in [How do I prompt the user from within a commit-msg hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417896/how-do-i-prompt-the-user-from-within-a-commit-msg-hook/3533735#3533735)

It is not possible to do what I've tried to achieve here.

Comment: What I wanted was to perform some setup on the server similar to what I can do with Capistrano, but I didn't find a way to do this.